# Encoding of same special characters

Tags: java, encoding, jasper-reports, special-characters, export-to-pdf

I use *JasperReports* for export PDF. I have a problem with special characters (è,à,û) whereas I don't have any problem with (é, € ). When I generate my file with *Jaspersoft Studio*, I don't have any problems (all special charactere are Ok). The problem occurs only when I export the PDF from my application (and just those characters don't work perfectly (è,à,û) and not (é, € )

Here is my code:

```
try {
          jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parametres, connection);
    } catch (JRException e) {
          throw e;
    } finally {
          connection.close();
    }

    return jasperPrint;
}

public byte[] exporterMoisPDF(String siret, long annee, long mois, String num_declarant, String date_declaration, String mois_lettre, String nomFichierJasper)throws Exception {
    byte[] rapportPDF=null;

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = genererExportMoisJasper(siret, annee, mois, num_declarant, date_declaration, mois_lettre, nomFichierJasper);  

    jasperPrint.setLocaleCode("UTF-8");
    rapportPDF = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);

    return rapportPDF;
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you don't have these characters in your fontname.ttf. Add proper font to jasperreports-fonts-x.x.x.jar and recompile it.

Answer (score 1):

Try insert the `<style name="style1" isDefault="true" pdfEncoding="Cp1252"/>` row to .jrxml file. (You can add it in a report designer too as "Style").

I also had problem with central european characters and it is solved by pdfEncoding="Cp1250" default style setting.

I tried the `<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding" value="Cp1250"/>` row too, but this had no effect in JasperReports 6.5.0 library on my environment.